# Get selection made by browser's Ctrl+F search

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cross-browser, selection

I have a treeview that has some of its nodes collapsed. I would like to expand them when user searches a page for some text and that text is inside a collapsed area. I've made tree's nodes hidden with `display: block-inline` and `overflow: hidden`, so that browser searches through them. The problem is that highlighting made by browser is not a `selection`, and I haven't found a way to access it.

1. How do I get programmatically the pseudo-selection made by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> search?
2. What are the other solutions for expanding those nodes (except the obvious one with overridden <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and own in-page search)?

The solution should work consistently in modern browsers.

Comment: You answered your own question: you can't detect search hilite. In Chrome when you're 'done' searching, the hilite becomes a selection. Maybe not true for all browsers, and not easy to check for.

Comment: Maybe if you make everything focusable with tabindex... But you'd still have to wait for 'done searching'.

Comment: Handle `<ctrl>+f` yourself and your problem is solved.

Comment: Implement search utilizing `:contains()` selector http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ ? , expand elements where `text` matches elements returned from `:contains()` ?